# How can I escape special HTML characters in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, escaping

Before I go and create a custom tag or Java method to do it, what is the standard way to escape HTML characters in JSP?

I have a String object and I want to display it in the HTML so that it appears to the user as is.

For example:

```
String a = "Hello < World";
```

Would become:

```
Hello &lt; World
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Short answer:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:out value="${myString}"/>
```

there is another option:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
${fn:escapeXml(myString)}
```

Comment: Be careful as there is a difference between escaping XML and HTML.

Comment: In most cases escaping XML is sufficient. BTW, the two code examples above work exactly the same. (c:out also escapes Xml, not Html).

Comment: If the concern is XSS prevention in HTML, XML escape should be sufficient (trying not get into xml vs. html advocacy here ...)

Comment: @AdamGent: can you give an example of a difference between escaping XML and HTML?

Comment: Yeah the famous dreaded `&apos;`: *The character entity references &lt;, &gt;, &quot; and &amp; are predefined in HTML and SGML, because <, >, " and & are already used to delimit markup. This notably does not include XML's &apos; (') entity. For a list of all named HTML character entity references, see List of XML and HTML character entity references (approximately 250 entries).* -- From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Comment: What also regularly pisses me off is there is a difference between attribute content escaping and element content escaping. [That is the content you put in attributes needs be escaped differently](http://site.jatl.googlecode.com/hg/apidocs/com/googlecode/jatl/MarkupUtils.html). I have a project called [JATL](http://code.google.com/p/jatl/) that makes generating  valid XHTML programmatically easier and respects the difference.

Comment: There are more differences between escapeXml and escapeHtml mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735900/what-is-the-difference-between-escapexml-and-escapehtml

Comment: Note that this will not prevent all XSS vulnerabilities! if you have `var show = ${fn:escapeXml(show)}` you don't need either `<` or `"` to exploit it!