# Enabling JavaServerPages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I feel like I am missing something - from what it seems, JSP comes out of the box with support for tags, as [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp) shows (the guy was asking a pure-jsp question and got an answer involving tags).
But if I try to run the given code

```
<c:out value="${myString}"/>
```

(with `myString` defined before, of course), the jsp just writes the above line into the html.

Do I have to do something extra to enable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSTL support is dependent on the server/servletcontainer used. Some ships with JSTL, others don't. This is regardless of the JSP/Servlet version. Usually, normal JEE servers such as WildFly/Payara/TomEE already ship with JSTL out the box, but barebones servletcontainers such as Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow don't. For them you'll need to install JSTL yourself.

It's actually pretty simple (assuming you're using Servlet 2.5 or newer):

1. Install JSTL as per instructions in this answer: [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/4928309#4928309).
2. Declare the tags in top of JSP as per [this JSTL documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/1.2/tagdocs/) (click any of the taglibs to see the declaration examples). For [JSTL core](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/1.2/tagdocs/c/tld-summary.html) it's the following:

   ```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

That's all. If you're (still) on Servlet 2.4, then you'll need to download [`jstl.jar` **and** `standard.jar`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip) instead (which are part of JSTL 1.1). Remaining steps are the same (just put in classpath and declare in top of JSP).

You may notice that some poor online tutorials would suggest to extract the JAR file and clutter the webapp's `web.xml` with the TLD declarations. You should never do that, this is a wrong suggestion which is caused by the change in taglib URI's during the JSTL 1.0 -> JSTL 1.1 step. Instead of updating the taglib URI's in JSP, ones decided to redefine the old taglib URI's in `web.xml` and it became a myth.

JSP itself ships with only the `<jsp:xxx>` tags out of the box. These are **not** part of JSTL.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)
- [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the taglib at the top of the JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks like a step in the right direction, but still not an exact answers, as I get the exception `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` 
If I need to install something, that's fine - but I thought this taglib comes "out of the box" with jsp.
Can you consider adding the answer to this to your answer?

Comment: @Noam: It only comes out of the box on certain versions of JSP (2.0 and older, in this case). But you didn't tell us anything about your setup, so I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: skaffman, this is actually not true. This is dependent on the server used.