# spring mvc page no binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I write a very simple spring-mvc example, **expect show "hello world" in page**. But it failed. It just show the **"${message}"** in the page.

below is my code and jsp. Is there any mistake I made? Or something configuration I missed? Thanks!

code:
Java：

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

    public class HomepageController extends AbstractController {

        @Override
        public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {



        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("message", "hello world");
        mav.setViewName("homepage");
        return mav;
        }

}
```

servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/home.htm">homepageController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="homepageController" class="com.sunjq.config.web.HomepageController"/>



</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/serviceContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/daoContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/appServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

jsp page:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  

    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
    <title>Homepage</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
    ${message}  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: What is it that failed ? Post the error message

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error is the page always show ${message} not the "hello world". I will put the page source in the topic thread head. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I just add the description, but no logs on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you did not enabled jstl and this is not related to spring mvc.
You need to :

1. Make sure your web container is installed with jstl
2. Add the following at the top of your page

The following answer provides good information on this topic 
[Enabling JavaServerPages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400038/enabling-javaserverpages-standard-tag-library-jstl-in-jsp)
I suggest using it as a reference.