# how to show map object data on jsp file using spring mvc

Tags: spring, hashmap

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "tempmap")
    public Map<Integer, String> getETypeMap(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws EmployeeBusinessException {
        Map<Integer, String> tempmap = employeeBS
                .fetchEmployeementType(userDetails.getTenantId(), userDetails.getLocaleId());
        return tempmap;
    }
```

here i have tempmap ie HashMap type of object, the problem is i want to use this oblect in my jsp file using SpringMVC framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JSTL forEach loop for iterating your map as follows:

```
 <c:forEach var="tempmap" items="${tempmap}">
   Key: ${tempmap.key}  - Value: ${tempmap.value}
 </c:forEach>
```

Hope it will help you.. use this link for more details about jstl [Enabling JavaServerPages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400038/enabling-javaserverpages-standard-tag-library-jstl-in-jsp)