# Passing apostrophe in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have jsp code as:

```
onclick="showURL('${result.url}')"
```

`${result.url}` is dynamic value. When an apostrophe comes in the URL I get the error.

I have tried all the methods like escape, encodeURI, replacing the single quotes with double but nothing works.

Script call is as follows:

```
function showURL(name){
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript escape quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just do this:

```
onclick=showURL("${result.url}");

function showURL (result_url) {
    alert("<c:out value='"+ result_url + "' />");
}
```

then you don't have to worry about escaping at all.

-tjw

Comment: I have tried above but getting error a attribute name undefined in onclick call. I have used escape once and it worked for all special character except apostrophe.

Comment: My code worked when i used c:out value directly in the java script body. var splCharUrl="<c:out value="${result.url}"/>"

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
${fn:escapeXml(myString)}
```

See: [How can I escape special HTML characters in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp)

Comment: I am using it as href. So when fn:escapeXML says as undefined attribute

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `${result.url}` returns a **valid URL**. Quotes are invalid in URLs. It sounds like that you're returning an URL with a query string with unencoded parameters like follows

```
public String getUrl() {
    return "page.jsp?foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar;
}
```

You need to change the method as follows

```
public String getUrl() {
    return "page.jsp?foo=" + URLEncoder.encode(foo, "UTF-8") + "&bar=" + URLEncoder.encode(bar, "UTF-8");
}
```

You cannot fix this in the JavaScript side with `escape()`, etc. It's already too late then.