# JSP c:set to value returned by x:out displays special characters code

Tags: jsp, jstl, xml-parsing

I have an xml document. When parsing that doc I want to do

```
<c:set var="fullName">
<x:out select="$character/fstName"/>.<x:out select="$character/famName"/>
</c:set>
```

and then later

```
<c:out value="${fullName}"/>
```

This displays special characters html code instead of the character itself (ie. apostrophe becomes &#38#039)

I have read a similar issue on that page "[how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp)" but this seems to be a solution for c:out **only**. I tried it in my case and it does not seem to work for x:out

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `<x:out>` will convert certain characters to their associated entity codes. If you don't want that to happen, try something like:

```
<x:out select="$character/fstName" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is the final solution:

```
<c:set var="fullName">
<x:out select="$character/fstName" escapeXml="false"/>.<x:out select="$character/famName" escapeXml="false"/>
</c:set>

<c:out value="${fullName}"/>
```

I guess *escapeXml="false"* is something to be used all the time if you nest your *x:out* in a *c:set* **unless** the expected nodes' content **has numbers only**.