# XSS Cross Site Scripting - Jsp <Input> tag

Tags: xss, cross-site

The following piece of code in my JSP caused a cross site scripting vulnerability on the input tag.

```
<form name="acctFrm" method="post" action="<%=contextPath%>/form/acctSummary?rpt_nm=FIMM_ACCT_SUMM_RPT">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Account Id:</td>
  <td>
   <input class="tbl1" type="text" id="acctId" name="acctId" size="20" maxlength="10" value="<%=rptBean.getAcctId()%>"/>
   <a href="javascript:doAcctSubmit()"><img class="tbl1" src="<%=contextPath%>/img/Submit.gif" border="0" /></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

During Penetration testing they were able to alert some random message to the user by injecting a alert script in the value attribute of the  tag as follows

```
<input class="tbl1" type="text" id="acctId" name="acctId" size="20" maxlength="10" value="1"><script>alert(12345)</script>" />
```

What is the problem here, and what would be the fix.

I was reading through some online references on XSS still I wasnt 100% sure on what could be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Deena

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the following solution,

The scriplet in the value attribute is the problem, I replaced it with jstl tag, I read somewhere that jstl tags have inbuild escaping mechanism to avoid xss issues.

```
<input class="tbl1" type="text" id="acctId" name="acctId" size="20" maxlength="10" value="<c:out value=${rptBean.acctId}"/>"/>
```

This works good for my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems the penetration testers were able to manipulate their session such that rptBean.getAcctId() would return an arbitrary string. If they could inject quotes and a right bracket, they could "force close" the `input` tag and insert their own `script` tag.

It looks like penetration testers got the method to return the string `1"><script>alert(12345)</script>`.

This indicates that you need to escape the data when writing to the page. I would suggest taking a look at the answer on [escaping HTML in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp).

Also, remember that code does not have to be "perfectly" formatted for a browser to render it "correctly". Here are some links on how attackers may try evade XSS filters:

- http://blog.whitehatsec.com/tag/filter-evasion/
- http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Always treat user data as "dangerous" and take care when rendering it on a page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems using `jstl` tag `<c:out value="">` in value attribute will cause errors in `jstl` `<form options>` tags,

more info
[XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

if `getAcctId()` returned data come from DB you can filter before sending  to client. for example check is data should be a number.