# XSL and JSP to show an HTML. Problems with &

Tags: html, jsp, xslt, escaping

I am using and XSL to transform a JSP into an HTML. While transforming I am linking a CSS.
When the request has a character & to show in an **input type="text"** or in a **textarea**, as shown below, the browser shows a blank page.

How could I show that character on the web page?

The url is defined in the web.xml.

**My JSP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x"%>

<c:import var="xslt" url="${initParam.URL_XSLT}" charEncoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<x:transform xslt="${xslt}">

<MyTag>
    <content>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="aName" value="${requestScope.myString}"/>
            <textarea name="aComment">${requestScope.myString2}</textarea>
        </div>
    </content>
</MyTag>
```

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
    <head>
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://general.css"/>
    ...
    </head>
    <xsl:element name="body">
         ...
         <xsl:copy-of select="MyTag/content/div"></xsl:copy-of>
         ...
    </xsl:element>
</html>
```

I tried changing

```
<xsl:copy-of-select>
```

by

```
<xsl:for-each select="//MyTag/content/*">
    <xsl:calltemplatename="node"/>
</xsl:for-each>

...


    <xsl:template name="node">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:if test="child::*">
                <xsl:for-each select="current()/*">
                    <xsl:call-template name="node"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- first attempt -->
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(text(),'&','&amp;')" />
            <!-- second attempt -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;![CDATA[', text(),']]&gt;')" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

To solving this I can´t modify the JSP. Just can modify the XSL.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:value-of` has an attribute `disable-output-escaping` to disable encoding of the amp.

```
<xsl:value-of select="..." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. On the server console I get this message The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="text()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

Comment: Is the XSLT processing the output of the JSP or is the output from the XSLT going in between the textarea tags? I don't know what requestScope.myString and .myString2 are.

Comment: The XSLT is used for obtaining the final HTML. During the transformation the CSS and other changes are made. requestScope.myString and requestScope.myString2 are data got from the request using EL.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. The XSLT is processing the output of the JSP, if I understand your situation. The problem is that the output of the JSP is not valid XML when a requestScope string contains & or other invalid XML characters. I know you said the JSP cannot be changed, but the request strings need to be escaped for XML by some means (e.g., fn:escapeXml). This SO answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp.

Comment: The JPS cannot be changed because is published in production enviroment and we have six applications. I must find a global solution. I am investigating if it is possible to modify the objects in the HttpRequest before sending them from the servlet to the JSP. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Finally I discarded this possible solution. I will escape the problematic characters in the servlet before sending the data in the request.setAttribute.