# italian characters not displayed properly while reading properties file in gwt

Tags: java, jsp, gwt

I am using gwt in my web application. Since it supports Italian language along with English (ISO-8859-1 charset)so have used gwt i18n.

The issue is some characters are not getting displayed properly on jsp page on browser. Characters like (Ó é etc) are displayed like diamond �. Reading properties file like

```
XXX_properties xx = gwt.create(XXX_properties.class)
```

Then, in view file reading properties with the getters of the above xx object.
Tried resource bundle tool to generate properties file but no success. Jsp page encoding is ISO-8859-1.

Anyone has the idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to print them on console? I mean where are u seeing the diamond symbols?

Comment: edited question..BTW I am displaying them on browser. Its a jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT mandates UTF-8 everywhere: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuidePropertiesFiles

If you can't use UTF-8 for your properties files, you can escape characters using the `\uNNNN` notation like in Java strings:

> Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence.

*Source:* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

See also http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score -1):

All special characters in HTML, such as those of italian or the spanish ñ need to be scaped. For example: città needs to be returned by the JSP as città

For a list of all the HTML scape characters look [here](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php). For a way to scape all characters from JSP see this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp).

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: Well, as you know it well enough to downvote, please explain what's incorrect in my answer and, if you don't mind, say me what do I need to learn about HTML that you did notice in my comment.

Comment: HTML is text, and text has to be encoded to bytes for transfer (or storage); that's the role of _encoding_. HTML is Unicode, so you don't need to use characters references (`&#nnn;` or `&#xHHHH;`) or character entities (à la `&agave;`) unless you cannot encode those characters to bytes per the encoding used (ISO-8859-1 for example is incapable of encoding Chinese or Arabic, or even the € sign; UTF-8 on the other hand is capable of encoding every Unicode character –the exact term is code-point–). Rule of thumb: use UTF-8 everywhere. I believe Wikipedia has good resources if you want more.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: +1. You were right, I found Wikipedia very useful.