# How to escape values in fmt.tld tags

Tags: java, html, jsp, escaping

How to escape values in fmt.tld tags:

```
 <fmt:param value='${user.lastName}' />
```

There is no validation for last name in UI as required by the application, so that the javascript snippets can be entered as last name So, how can I escape the values printed in Jsp page by the fmt tags.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: sorry chinna, there was some issue with my formatting and the code was not displaying, thanks Vivek.

Answer (score 1):

```
<fmt:param value="${fn:escapeXml(user.lastName)}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution**

I got a working solution using JSTL functions library which has an escapeXml method. so i could just use it like this,

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<fmt:param value='${fn:escapeXml(user.lastName)}' />
```

This [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp?rq=1) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The fmt:message doesn't escape characters too. You can also use the c:out tag.

```
<fmt:message key="${inputFromUser}" var="inputFromUser"/>
<c:out value="${inputFromUser}"/>
```