# spring mvc project "invalid character used in text string" error in .jsp file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, syntax-error, invalid-characters

I want to share my sample code in my website. And I used Punctuation marks(such as; &, *, % etc.) in jsp file like below;

```
<pre>
/*
if(sensB>sensA && diffB>200)
{
ctr++;
delay(2500); // INCREMENT
}
*/
</pre>
```

But I had got warnings;

> Description   Resource Path Location Type Invalid character used in text
>   string (/*if(sensB>sensA && diffB>200) { ctr++; delay(2500); //
>   INCREMENT }*/)

How can I get this error?

Comment: if you use the pre tag to display code, the HTML encoding/escaping is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `shi` metntioned in the comment you need to escape your content (code string) in JSP

```
<c:out value="${myCodeString}"/>
```

there is another option:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
${fn:escapeXml(myCodeString)}
```

Got from [How can I escape special HTML characters in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp)