# How do I prevent XSS in JSP scriptlet exceptions?

Tags: java, jsp, xss

I have a JSP page with a scriptlet of the form

```
<%
String imageId = request.getParameter("imageId");
if(getImageById == null){
    throw new JspException("No data found for " + imageId);
}
%>
```

When the exception is thrown, the request parameter "imageId" is printed, allowing an XSS attack.

What's the best way to sanitize the input to Exception() to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what image id should be.

If it's a number then try to parse it first.  If you are expecting string data (like a GUID) you chould check that it follows the spec.

In either case - if the Id is not valid then don't pass it back - just say no data found.

If the ID can be any random set of characters, then on the JSP side use the JSTL

```
<c:out value="${myId}"/>
```

or

```
escapeXml(myId)
```

from

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="t" %>
```

This may help:  [How can I escape special HTML characters in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp)

Or this:  [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Here is a sanitizer by OWASP:  https://github.com/owasp/java-html-sanitizer

Comment: I've been using <c:out> tags and fn:escapeXml() in other areas, but I can't use either of those inside a scriptlet, can I?

Comment: I just added another SO question for Java.  Do you need to display the ID?  Do you have anymore info about the format of the ID?

Comment: This isn't my code.  I can look up some examples of the ID, but I can't be certain that I can account for every possible valid form as intended by whoever wrote it.  I was hoping something simple like <c:out> or fn:escapeXml but for pure Java would exist.  I need to fix the code while leaving it as close to its functioning form as possible, which means displaying the ID.

Comment: The 2nd link and 3rd links have utilities that can escape HTML.  You would need to include the library in your code base.