# "&" is not showing in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

My jsp page not showing "&" I have one string and i am fetching value 
    from backend side. nameStringis coming from backend side as "Orders & 
    Links". But on jsp its showing only Orders.. I want to fetch the full name 
    on jsp as well . Follwing code snippet

```
      <s:label name="Display Name *" class="bold"/>
      <s:text name="nameString" id="displayName" value="${mrudAction.nameString}"
              class="auto-adjust check-empty"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

& is a special HTML character. What ever tag library you are using - see if there is an attribute you can add to the text tag to escape HTML.

You could also store the string as  `Orders &amp; Links`

If your using Struts you could also see if the property tag makes sense 
https://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html

See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp and [How can I escape special HTML characters in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475839/how-can-i-escape-special-html-characters-in-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

text tag is used to pull message from resource bundle. you would be using property tag and use escapeHtml parameters of property tag.

```
<s:propety  value="${mrudAction.nameString}"  escapeHtml="true" >
```